# Select part of value in one column and copy it to another column - sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update

I have the following sql query that needs to be fixed to trim any whitespace (beginning and end) of the selection. I also need it to delete the "lastname" part from the firstname column:

```
UPDATE customer_address_entity
   SET lastname = RIGHT(firstname,LENGTH(firstname)-LOCATE(' ',firstname)) 
 WHERE lastname = ''
```

For instance if the column "firstname" has "Jo   de blog " in it and "lastname" column is empty I want the "firstname" column to contain "Jo" and the "lastname" column to contain "de Blog"

Comment: i'd consider using TRIM and SUBSTRING_INDEX functions .  I also strongly recommend testing expressions using a SELECT statement, verifying results, before we incorporate those into an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would apporach it so.

When the firstname has 2 surnames it would take the last two
When the firstname has 1 surnames it would take also only the last
With increasing number of words in firstname. you need a more sophisticated algorithm to find the right index

> ```
> CREATE TABLE customer_address_entity (
>   `id`INT,
>   `firstname` varchar(25),
>   `lastname` varchar(25) 
> );
>
> INSERT INTO customer_address_entity
>   (`id`,`firstname`,  `lastname`)
> VALUES
>   (1,'Jo de blog ',''),(2,'Jo blog ',''),(3,'test2','test2');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM customer_address_entity
> ```
>
> ```
> id | firstname   | lastname
> -: | :---------- | :-------
>  1 | Jo de blog  |         
>  2 | Jo blog     |         
>  3 | test2       | test2
> ```

> ```
>     UPDATE `customer_address_entity` 
>     SET `lastname` = TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(`firstname`), " "
>     , IF(LENGTH(TRIM(`firstname`)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(TRIM(`firstname`), ' ', '')) > 1,-2,-1)))
>     ,
>     firstname = TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(`firstname`), " ", 1)) 
>     WHERE `lastname` = '';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM customer_address_entity
> ```
>
> ```
> id | firstname | lastname
> -: | :-------- | :-------
>  1 | Jo        | de blog 
>  2 | Jo        | blog    
>  3 | test2     | test2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=3326982c18bd2d166ac651ce6798abee)*

Comment: Is there anyway to make this work so it trimmed the "lastname" part, just in case there is multiple spaces after the "firstname" part.

Comment: yes you can trim it like i done it in teh answer it is only text

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky, because your expression would not produce the expected results if the string starts with a space.

I would use:

```
substring(trim(firstname), locate(' ', trim(firstname)) + 1)
```

This basically starts by removing leading and trailing spaces from the string, then selects everything after the first space within the string.

In your `update` statement:

```
UPDATE `customer_address_entity` 
SET `lastname` = substring(trim(firstname), locate(' ', trim(firstname)) + 1)
WHERE `lastname` = ''
```

If there may be multiple spaces between the first name and last name, then you can `trim()` the resulting string too:

```
trim(substring(trim(firstname), locate(' ', trim(firstname)) + 1))
```

Comment: Yes, some strings will contain multiple spaces, please clarify where we would incorporate the last part of the code you mention. Thank you

Comment: Also, need the "lastname" part to be removed from the "firstname" column. Cheers